# extracting value from a "timestamp" labeled dictionery

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, timestamp

Lets say I have this dictionry (using pandas timestamp):

```
d = {Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'): {'intangibleAssets': 295, 'capitalSurplus': 415},Timestamp('2020-03-30 00:00:00'): {'intangibleAssets': 400, 'capitalSurplus': 50}}
```

How can i exctarct a single value, like 295 located in d["Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00')"]["intangibleAssets"]?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Timestamp` because our dictionary key type is `pd.Timestamp` not `str`.

```
import pandas as pd
d[pd.Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00')]["intangibleAssets"]
295
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pandas, you can transform to a dataframe and use `loc` or `.iloc` passing the row and column that you are interested in:

with `.loc`:

```
d = {'2020-06-30 00:00:00': {'intangibleAssets': 295, 'capitalSurplus': 415},'2020-03-30 00:00:00': {'intangibleAssets': 400, 'capitalSurplus': 50}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).loc['intangibleAssets','2020-06-30 00:00:00']
df
295
```

OR `iloc`:

```
d = {'2020-06-30 00:00:00': {'intangibleAssets': 295, 'capitalSurplus': 415},'2020-03-30 00:00:00': {'intangibleAssets': 400, 'capitalSurplus': 50}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).iloc[0,0]
df
295
```

Comment: Thanks, thats great but unfortunately I have many dict`, each one in a diffrent order...

Answer (score 0):

Below function is generic and can be implemented to any number of dictionary.
To get the keys:

```
def matchingKeys(dictionary, searchString):
    return [key for key,val in dictionary if searchString in val]
```

To get the values:

```
def matchingValues(dictionary, searchString):
    return [val for key,val in dictionary if searchString in val]
```

To get both:

```
def matchingElements(dictionary, searchString):
    return {key:val for key,val in dictionary if searchString in val}
```